# Count of last status per day / week

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

is it possible to get the count of last statuses in a day / week via DAX measure?
I want to count only the last status of *backlog* tickets in a day / week. The backlog is calculated on ticket level (below table **Data  per ticket**) as accumulated difference of count of opened and closed tickets:

```
Backlog:=
VAR MaxDate = MAX('q_Calendar'[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE([Opened]-[Closed],CALCULATETABLE(ALL('q_Calendar')),'q_Calendar'[Date]<=MaxDate)
```

There are 2 source tables, example below:

**Data per step**

| Ticket Number | Step | Step Date | StepStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 | 8/25/2021 11:06 AM | 10 |
| 00001 | 2 | 8/25/2021 12:05 PM | 20 |
| 00001 | 3 | 8/27/2021 01:13 PM | 30 |
| 00001 | 4 | 8/27/2021 03:33 PM | 40 |
| 00002 | 1 | 8/27/2021 10:01 AM | 10 |
| 00002 | 2 | 8/27/2021 10:05 AM | 20 |
| 00002 | 3 | 8/30/2021 08:47 AM | 30 |
| 00002 | 4 | 8/30/2021 08:59 AM | 35 |
| 00002 | 5 | 8/30/2021 04:25 PM | 30 |
| 00002 | 6 | 8/31/2021 07:49 AM | 40 |

**Data per ticket**

| Ticket Number | Date Created | Date Resolved | TicketStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 8/25/2021 11:06 AM | 8/30/2021 07:51 AM | Closed |
| 00002 | 8/27/2021 10:01 AM | 8/31/2021 07:55 AM | Closed |

So in case the ticket is closed, it should be omitted in the status calculation of that and all future days.

The result should be a bar chart with following data:

| Date | StepStatus | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/25/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 8/26/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 8/27/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 8/27/2021 | 40 | 1 |
| 8/28/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 8/28/2021 | 40 | 1 |
| 8/29/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 8/29/2021 | 40 | 1 |
| 8/30/2021 | 30 | 1 |

There is a relationship between per step and per ticket data. 1 ticket to many steps. So if I take the StepStatus and use the backlog calculating measure, the results are multiplied per each StepStatus type.

Comment: Do you have Calendar table? Add more info about relationship between tables. Data per step <-> Data per ticket (by ticket number? )

Answer (score 1):

For example you can create this kind of table ( physical or virtual (to use inside another mesure)):

```
Table = 
var __TickAllDayBetween = GENERATE(Sheet1, CALENDAR(Sheet1[Date Created],Sheet1[Date Resolved]))
var LookupTable =  ADDCOLUMNS(SUMMARIZE(ADDCOLUMNS(SELECTCOLUMNS(Sheet2, "TicketNumber", Sheet2[Ticket Number], "StepDate", DATE(YEAR(Sheet2[Step Date]), MONTH(Sheet2[Step Date]),DAY(Sheet2[Step Date]))), "MAX", CALCULATE(max(Sheet2[Step Date]), filter(ALL(Sheet2[Step Date]), DATEVALUE(Sheet2[Step Date]) = [StepDate]))),[TicketNumber],[MAX]),"LastStatusPerDay", CALCULATE( min(Sheet2[StepStatus]), Filter(ALL(Sheet2[Step Date]),[MAX] = Sheet2[Step Date] )))
var __return =  SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATE(__TickAllDayBetween, TOPN(1,FILTER(LookupTable, DATEVALUE([MAX]) <= [Date] && [TicketNumber] = [Ticket Number]), [MAX], DESC)), "Date",[Date], "Status",[LastStatusPerDay])
return __return
```

[image]